# How To Show All Results Including Values That Equal Zero

Tags: postgresql, syntax

Select books AS books_read, Count(*) as page_count

FROM books_rollup

WHERE books IN (Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3')

Group By books

My Results:

books_read   page_count

Value 1              415

Value 3              500

Value 2 is 0 and does not display in the output. How to show all results including Value 2 like below:

Books_Read   Page_Count

Value 1              415

Value 2              0

Value 3              500

I expect for the output to not omit 0 like below:

Books_Read   Page_Count

Value 1              415

Value 2              0

Value 3              500

Value 2 is not present in my results:

Books_Read   Page_Count

Value 1              415

Value 3              500

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution I use `CASE` in `COUNT`:

```
Select books AS books_read, 
count(
case when (books = 'Value 1' and is not null) then 1
     when (books = 'Value 2' and is not null) then 1
     when (books = 'Value 3' and is not null) then 1
     else 0 end)
FROM books_rollup
WHERE books IN ('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3')
Group By books
```

Comment: Thank you for having a look and providing a response! I attempted to utilize case in count however, I saw an error on "is not null" and changed to "not null" and this runs successfully although the 0 value is still not present.

Comment: @Knowledge so in you DB are `value 2` ? or just V1 and V3 ?